# LocationListener Alert Dialog Multiple Pop Up

Tags: android, dialog, location, listener, alert

I have a location listener which pops up an alert dialog on proximity. However, it will keep popping up the same alert dialog again and again as I walk around. Is there a way to disable the location listener when an alert dialog pops up and re-enable the location listener when the user submits or dismisses the alert dialog?

Comment: I think you'll need to post some of your code so we can see what you're working with. That will make it much easier to suggest changes to achieve the desired effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you show the alertdialog

```
 alertDialog.show();
```

call

```
 locManager.removeUpdates(locListener);
  //here locManager is your LocationManager object and locListener is your LocationListener
```

Then after the user clicks on some button of alert dialog register for location listener again like this..

```
  alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

   //here register for location listener again..

     locManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, updateInterval, updateDistance, locListener);

} });
```